# 09 Citi golf 1.4i timing jumps around

Tags: timing

I checked my timing but its not stable when i check it with the timing light, the v-notch is mark is jumping , a little bit in front of the mark then on the mark and then after the mark and carry on like this, car pulls fine and everything but have about 2 slight jerks on low rev when driving. Any idea what can cause it?

Comment: The engine control module is controlling the timing... Timing lights were for cars with ignition systems based on mechanical advance systems. The engine parameters should be checked with a computer interfacing with the cars systems ie OBDII for example.

Comment: Do you have the vacuumm advance line disconnected from the distributor?  I don't know what ignition system the '09 cars use but I assume it's the same as the earlier cars.

Comment: Its got an electronic distributor , no vacuum line on it.

Comment: In that case I would assume that it's running a fixed backplate and a 3-pin hall sensor is sending crank position to the ECU.  I would guess that it's based on something light the Bosch Digifant fuel injection system.  As stated above, this likely means that the ECU is responsible for the timing mark jumping around and your best course of action is to read any stored ECU fault codes.  If you pull out the ash tray from the centre console, you'll find the OBD diagnostic port into which you can plug something like VCDS.

Comment: Thanks Steve Matthews , I'll see if I can get someone to run some diagnostics for me.